# Filter list by Author (Created By) field with rest api - SP Online 2019

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api, filter, 2019

So I'm sending a REST query like:

```
_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List')/getitems?$select=AuthorId
```

It works fine, I see 49 records with `AuthorId`. Now I want to filter by this column. Then I want to filter this list by `AuthorId` field:

```
_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List')/getitems?$select=AuthorId&$filter=AuthorId eq <id>
```

But I got error:

```
error: {code: "-2147024809, System.ArgumentException"}
value: "Column 'AuthorId' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.
```

I don't get this error when I change query for something like this:

```
_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List')/getitems?$select=AuthorId&$filter=Author eq <id>
```

But I also have no results for this, and I should.

I don't know If it is important information but my list is a library also.

I saw a lot of posts about this problem but none of it worked for me.

Is there any way to do this or any documentation information why it is so messed up?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
<siteUrl>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List')/items?$select=Title,Author/Id&$expand=Author&$filter=Author/Id eq <id>
```

**Microsoft official documentations**:

1. [Complete basic operations using SharePoint REST endpoints](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints)
2. [Working with lists and list items with REST](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest)
3. [Working with folders and files with REST](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest)

Comment: Hi @Iwoo, Does this answers your question? If Yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it will help others with same problem in future. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list. If you have any doubt please ask here.